# Inverse fourier transform by using a random phase and an original magnitude (matlab)

Tags: image-processing, fft, ifft

I want a image. Firstly I want to do fourier transform and get the magnitude and phase information. And then make a new random phase, finally use the changed random phase and original magnitude to make the inverse fourier transform. But I can not achieve it?

The code is shown here.

```
 img   = imread('flag.jpg');
 imafft = fftn(double(img));
 mag = abs(imafft);
 phi= angle(imafft);
 s= size (img);
 rand_phase= 4*pi*(rand(s(1),s(2))-0.5);
 newfft = mag.*exp(i*rand_phase);
 ima_out = ifft2(newfft); 
 figure(2);
 imagesc(abs(ima_out));
 axis image;
 title('Ramdom phase version');
```

The problem is in the sentence of `newfft = mag.*exp(i*rand_phase);` I do not know how to modify.

Who can help me? Thank you so much.

Comment: What exactly is "problem"? Do you get an error?

Comment: Have you defined "i" as imaginary unit? In Matlab that should be either "j" or "1i".

Comment: You are right. Now my problem is the IFFT. What should I do to make a IFFT by using a mag and phase? Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

You image is not an $N \times M$ matrix. It's actually an $N \times M \times 3$ array of numbers. I assume that's why you're using `fftn` instead of `fft2` to take its Fourier transform.

You have to either

1. convert your image to grayscale; or
2. process each component independently.

To work get grayscale, we can naïvely average over the RGB colors like so:

```
img = mean(double(img),3)
```

To work with all three components independently, your phase array needs to have an extra dimension:

```
rand_phase= 4*pi*(rand(s(1),s(2), s(3))-0.5);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion. That is the problem. I change to the gray scale, the problem is solved. But I have a new problem, I use the words of 'newfft = mag.*exp(i*rand_phase);' to do the IFFT, but the result does not come, what should I do to use a mag and phase to produce a new picture. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @HEHongShen I am facing the same problem, were you able to solve it. Please help me if you solved it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `newfft = mag.*exp(1i*rand_phase);` instead of `newfft = mag.*exp(i*rand_phase);` `1i` denotes the imaginary unit.